# Salesforce Buy Button

Tags: e-commerce, community-cloud

As we learned during dreamforce and in several newsletters Salesforce is "adding the buy button to communities".

From my understanding a "buy button" is not part of salesforce standard UI. Therefore the buy button is delivered by installing managed packages. (or has to be developed by yourself)

**Therefore I there are several questions:**

1. Which "buy button" solutions are available?
2. Is it possible with these solutions to implement "public" e-commerce shops? (no login required / guest mode)
3. Is it possible to use your custom and optimized URLs?

During dreamforce I was talking to cloudcraze but it was hard to get my questions answered.

*(I know that all these features a doable with salesforce. I've implemented all of them 5 years ago for our client [www.die-akademie.de](http://www.die-akademie.de))*